# databaseInstances API does not return ipAddress

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-apis-explorer

When running the sample "Try this API" for Cloud SQL Instances List API, the result shows a valid IP address in the output.

```
"ipAddresses": [
    {
     "ipAddress": "35.xxx.xxx.xxx",
     "type": "PRIMARY"
    }
```

But when I use the sample Go code for the same project, it comes out as a hex value that I do not see how to convert.

```
IpAddresses:[]*sqladmin.IpMapping{(*sqladmin.IpMapping)(0xc0000axxxx
```

How can I get the result of the call in the Go program to appear like it does in the online example?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please see how to make a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To avoid link rotting (and having to google for it), the code you're referring to is best included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've attempted to print an array of *pointers* to IpMapping objects, so you are seeing the hexadecimal address of the pointer. You can see this happen in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/8qDCP7H3aei).

You can see the actual IP address if you actually inspect the IpMapping itself, like in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/NtqfZc50i64)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, David.  I finally got it working and you are correct.  I was looking at the whole array instead of the indexed entries.  I ended up doing this:

```
for idx := 0; idx < len(databaseInstance.IpAddresses) ; idx++ {
fmt.Printf("%v ",databaseInstance.IpAddresses[idx].IpAddress)}
```